# Household Bluetooth network

Tags: networking, bluetooth

What is a best way to have ability to connect Bluetooth enabled PC and cellphone all over the house? Connection possible only in same room with PC, i want to extend now.

Does passive repeater (two antennas connected with coaxial one near the PC BT and other in remote room) helps? Or can i build BT network such as Multi-AP Roaming for Wi-Fi? Which hardware i need to use in that case as cheaper as possible?

Answer (score 0):

-->The range depends not only on the transmitter, but also on the mobile phone which is receiving files.
-->The range depends on atmospheric, geographic, urban conditions (vendors provide the best achievable range in perfect conditions).
-->The bigger range, the slower transmission speed.

-->To increase the range Minimize as many large obstacles as possible between the Bluetooth-connected devices.
-->Range also is affected by large furniture between devices, so move the electronics or rearrange furniture to improve performance.
-->Also you can purchase a known Bluetooth booster,which plugs into Bluetooth-enabled equipment, boosts Bluetooth devices' signals, greatly increasing the range beyond the standard 30 feet. The total extension depends on the individual booster's power.

Turn off or move away from competing wireless signals, such as Wi-Fi connections. Wi-Fi works like Bluetooth, but is much stronger. The signals can disrupt Bluetooth connections, shortening the Bluetooth's range.

Comment: Even if i will reach that "perfect conditions" it still not enough because i need way more radius than 10 meters. So my only solution it's multiple BT transmitters combined in one network (if it's possible at all) or BT repeaters.